# Unable to get the list after using sendkeys in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, css, selenium

After passing text through sendkeys I am not getting list to select the item.

1. Could you please advise, what is the issue.
2. website is www.kuoni.co.uk

---

```
WebElement createHolidayText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"span12 sections\"] >ul > li > a[data-section-id=\"972cfe76_6ba0_408d_a6df_0ef2d74cf943\"] > span"));
assertThat("Create Holiday Text has changed. Please check!", createHolidayText.getText(), is("Create your holiday"));

WebElement clickCreateYourHoliday = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"span12 sections\"] >ul > li > a[data-section-id=\"972cfe76_6ba0_408d_a6df_0ef2d74cf943\"] > span"));
clickCreateYourHoliday.click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("iframe[src=\"http://booking.kuoni.co.uk/include/home/include-book-home11.html\"]")));

WebElement searchFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src=\"http://booking.kuoni.co.uk/include/home/include-book-home11.html\"]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(searchFrame);

WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=\"destination\"]"));
destination.sendKeys("SSH");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem through your code.

The problem is when iframe gets opened - the destination textbox is taking time to populate all the Entries from where the data is retrieved.

I have used below code and it works for me:

```
  driver.get("http://www.kuoni.co.uk");
      WebElement createHolidayText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"span12 sections\"] >ul > li > a[data-section-id=\"972cfe76_6ba0_408d_a6df_0ef2d74cf943\"] > span"));
      assertThat("Create Holiday Text has changed. Please check!", createHolidayText.getText(), is("Create your holiday"));

      WebElement clickCreateYourHoliday = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=\"span12 sections\"] >ul > li > a[data-section-id=\"972cfe76_6ba0_408d_a6df_0ef2d74cf943\"] > span"));
      clickCreateYourHoliday.click();

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("iframe[src=\"http://booking.kuoni.co.uk/include/home/include-book-home11.html\"]")));

      WebElement searchFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src=\"http://booking.kuoni.co.uk/include/home/include-book-home11.html\"]"));
      driver.switchTo().frame(searchFrame);
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=\"destination\"]"));
      destination.click();
      Thread.sleep(6000);
      destination.sendKeys("SSH" );
      destination.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
      destination.sendKeys("H" );
```